# Write CMD output to text file using R

Tags: r, batch-file

I'm writing a cryptocurrency mining application where I want to log the output of the miner to a text file. Each miner can be started by using a Windows Batch File or a Windows Command Script. When I try to use the `shell` function like so:

```
shell("cd C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Mining\\bin\\ccminer & SIGT >> C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Mining\\logs\\sigt.txt")
```

where SIGT is the Windows Command Script, R doesn't accept any new inputs, since the process in the command line hasn't finished (as it runs indefinitely). I want to be able to analyse the output, stop the mining, change to a different mining program etc., all within R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.